# Treat TCP as MQTT protocol

Tags: wireshark, mqtt

I have packets captured during not encrypted MQTT communication:

[image: Treat]

Protocol is detected as TCP. How to ask Wireshark to analyze packets as MQTT?

[image]

UPD

In case I set MQTT server work on default 1883 port I Wireshark treats packets like MQTT. But how to ask Wireshark treat packets lime MQTT when it runs on on default port?

[image]

Comment: Can you check if your MQTT port is set at 1883? You can check it from - Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> MQTT.

Comment: Yes, it recognizes packets on 1883 port, but how to do the same on not default port?

Comment: Can you give it a try by unticking - Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> TCP -> 'allow subdissector to reassemble tcp streams' ?

Comment: Unticking `Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> TCP -> 'allow subdissector to reassemble tcp streams'` not helps

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a packet, and select `Decode as...`. A dialog appears, which should contain rules for the port you've selected. In the "Current" column, it will contain `(none)`. Double click that cell, and the contents will change to a drop-down list. From that, select "MQTT", and press OK.